# how to fix occasional stutter in my game?

Tags: ios, performance, position, sprite-kit, sknode

**The context**:

In my SKScene I have:

1) a few sprites with no physics controlled by touch using touchesMoved: which instantly changes sprite position property based on touch location,

2) one sprite that while colliding with the others changes its physicsBody.velocity instantly.

That's all - no other fancy processing.

**The issue**:

I found occasional and random stuttering all of the sprites independently without any FPS dropping.

**The questions**:

In the context of my performance issue:

1) Is there any reason to update sprite position or velocity in update: method rather than update them instantly?

2) Is there any sense to use SKAction rather than changing directly position or velocity property?

3) If 2 then can make any difference running SKActions instantly or run them in update: method?

[Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH4-SW1) about
    update:
method:

> This is the primary place to implement your own in-game simulation, including input handling, artificial intelligence, game scripting, and other similar game logic. Often, you use this method to make changes to nodes or to run actions on nodes.

but nothing more like "*must,...*" or "*should, because...*".

4) Isn't SpriteKit done like all the changes made to the nodes instantly are processed in respective loop update phase or do I have always go to the appropriate loop method to make/fire changes there to avoid any rendering performance loss or interference?

Comment: Use Instruments to narrow down possible cause of the issue. Typically "occasional stuttering" comes from loading resources at runtime, or just doing too much in a single frame (like creating 10 sprites at once). You need to post more details about the actual problems (including code) and fewer, more concrete questions. You seem to be stabbing in the dark with your questions (some make no sense, some can't be answered definitive, with answers depending on context you did not provide). You first need to narrow down the issue you're having (ie Instruments, remove some code temporarily, etc).

Comment: OK, but maybe the 4th question is narrow enough?

Comment: All the resources are loaded at once at the app start and there is hardly a few Kbytes.

Comment: 4) Depends on the code you are using. For instance using NSTimer, dispatch_* or performSelector could in theory violate the SpriteKit update loop. In general see the SK programming guide, there's a graph that explains the update loop well. Things aren't rendered until after the update method has run, the actions evaluated and physics simulated.

Comment: Consider using [-applyForce:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPhysicsBody/applyForce:) instead of manually setting the velocity. Apple's [Sprite Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html) says: "When a body is in the simulation, it is more common for the velocity to be adjusted based on forces applied to the body."